# Move/Rename a Jar in artifactory

Tags: curl, gradle, artifactory

I am trying to rename a Jar in artifactory.

Can someone guide me on which of these options is the best and simplest way?

1. Using curl
2. Using gradle

Comment: If you're trying to rename a jar that is already published to artifactory, you should use the REST api. If you're trying to set a name while publishing, you should use the correct gradle configuration.

Comment: @RaGe Could please share the syntax for REST API..I am trying to rename a jar which is already published to artifactory.

Comment: use Move: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-MoveItem

Comment: my folder structure is like (http://art.com/data/xyz-3.0.jar). I want to rename the Jar to (xyz-4.0.jar) & paste in the same location. can you post curl command to do it [curl -u user:pass ]

Comment: I tried the below curl command but it doesn't work  curl -x MOVE --header 'Destination:http://example.org/new.txt' 'http://example.org/old.txt'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using curl and REST API (move item):

```
curl -X POST http://hostname:port/api/move/libs-release-local/org/acme?to=/ext-releases-local/org/acme-new&dry=1
```

Comment: +1 This works fine as-is (add `-u` or other authentication options as needed), with the caveat that some Artifactory installations are set up to have all URLs relative to a subdirectory instead of the root HTTP path, for example I've seen setups where the URL needs to start with `https://hostname:port/artifactory/api/[...]` instead of just `https://hostname:port/api/[...]`